When is this rational function of exponentials actually rational-valued?
This has come up in my research, and I am sorry if it is obvious. I am looking at the following expression
$$
m\frac{\tanh(xm)}{\tanh(x)} = m\frac{e^{2xm}-1}{e^{2xm}+1} \frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1},
$$
where $m \in \mathbb{N}$ is natural and $x>0$ is real positive. When is this expression equal to a rational number? Can we characterize the set of $m$ and $x$ that satisfy this or say something otherwise meaningful about it? I thank all helpers.

So $k$ is a real number, or positive integer?

@ThomasAndrews $k$ is a positive real, sorry about that

I would use another variable other than $k,$ because it reads in exponents as meaning an integer. Either $x,y,t,$ or maybe a Greek letter.

It would work for all $x = \mathrm{ln}(k)$ where $1<k\in\Bbb Q$.

thank you. Does that cover all cases or can we characterize when $\ln(k)$ is rational?

Yes, this will give a good same of values $x.$ Not sure we can prove it gives all of them.

$\ln(k)$ is never rational when $k$ is rational. @Croc2Alpha

Let $e^x = q \in \Bbb Q>1$. then immediately we see that $x = \text{ln}(q)$. since $\text{ln}$ is bijective between $\Bbb R > 1$ and $\Bbb R$, it should give all solutions.

Indeed, $x=\frac12\ln k$ works, for any $k$ rational, and I doubt this is close to all values $x.$

@paulina, being  bijective doesn't mean that it gives all . For example, $f(x)=x^3+x$ is bijective, every rational value returns a rational value, but there are solutions to $f(x)=r$ for any rational $r,$ and they are not all of the form $x$ rational. E.g., the real such that $f(x)=\frac12$ is not rational.

that is a different problem. in your case, the set so that $f(R) = \Bbb Q$ isnt $\Bbb Q$, but $f^{-1}(\Bbb Q)$. Now replace $f$ with $\text{exp}$, $f^{-1}$ with $\text{ln}$ and $\Bbb Q$ with $\Bbb Q>1$.

one mistake i made is that all my $>$ should be $\geq$, since $e^0$ and $\text{ln}(1)$ are obviously rational.
